# How to keep cmd open after task schedule

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a really simple task that uses `sdelete` command as a scheduled task but when I run the task the CMD just flickers on and off and does not perform the task, so I want to see what it is doing on the CMD to troubleshoot the problem by keeping it on after it has completed.

program/script:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

Argument:

```
/c "sdelete -z"
```

Start in:

```
C:\Users
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new text file and put this in it:

```
sdelete -z
pause
```

Save this file as `test.bat`, making sure to select "All Files" in the filetype dropdown, to avoid the file being named `test.bat.txt`.

Now run the batch file.The `pause` command will pause script execution and allow you to see any output in the command window.

Answer (score 2):

Place `pause` at the end of the script and it will pause until a key press is reconsidered

Although if this is not a script and just an argument place `> output.txt` at the end and it will output the argument to a file called `output.txt` in the location it was run

Answer (score 0):

The argument " /c " after cmd.exe just carries out the command and then terminates the CMD, but you can use

> cmd.exe /k "sdelete -z"

that carries out the command too, but remains.